# Need javascript regex to check string starts with U or C and with length of 10

Tags: javascript, regex

I need javascript regular expression to check string starting with U or C. Also it should be of length 10.

I tried this `^U|C{9}$` but not getting proper results.

Answer (score 1):

You should group the tokens when using `|` operator, so as to get intended results. Also, you must use `.`(any character except new-line) and make sure it is 9 characters long.

You can also use character class as in `/^[UC].{9}$/`

```
/^(U|C).{9}$/
```

You can also use simple javascript to do this

```
var chr = str.charAt(0);
if((chr == "U" || chr == "C") && str.length == 10){
   // valid
}
```

Comment: char is a reserved keyword

Comment: @prashant glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex instead:

```
^[UC].{9}$
```

The `.` will match any character, which you missed out.